# GCE Ingress expose websocket service

Tags: kubernetes, websocket, google-compute-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I want to expose 2 services:

- web application at **example.com** port **80**
- web sockets at **example.com/app/ws** port **8000**

with given configuration:

---

```
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "Service"
metadata:
  name: "web-app-service"
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
spec:
  type: "LoadBalancer"
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: "web-app"
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      name: "http"
---
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "Service"
metadata:
  name: "web-sockets-service"
spec:
  type: "NodePort"
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: "web-sockets"
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
      name: "http"
---
apiVersion: "networking.k8s.io/v1"
kind: "Ingress"
metadata:
  name: "web-app-ingress"
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "example.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: "/app/ws"
            pathType: "Prefix"
            backend:
              service:
                name: "web-sockets-service"
                port:
                  number: 8000
          - path: "/"
            pathType: "Prefix"
            backend:
              service:
                name: "web-app-service"
                port:
                  number: 80
---
```

I can reach web application at **example.com**, but trying to communicate with **example.com/app/ws** results with failed to connect - timeout. Curl call to internal service IP at port 8000 results with success, so im misconfigured something at ingress configuation of web sockets

```
curl -i -N -H "Connection: Upgrade" -H "Upgrade: websocket" example.com/app/ws:8000
```

results with timeout

internal cluster call (different pod than websocket server):

```
curl -i -N -H "Connection: Upgrade" -H "Upgrade: websocket" <web-sockets-service ip>/app/ws:8000
```

result with success websocket server response

Websocat:

request to service:

```
> websocat ws://<web-sockets-service ip>:8000/app/ws
{"event":"connection_established","data":"{\"socket_id\":\"620572367.722478523\",\"activity_timeout\":30}"}
```

request to ingress:

```
> websocat ws://example.com:8000/app/ws
websocat: WebSocketError: I/O Failure
websocat: error running
```

Comment: Are you expecting 101 response from curl to check it? It's better to try with https://github.com/vi/websocat client to test web socket connections instead of curl

Comment: Websocat connection check added for both internal service call and external call to ingress. It don't provide any additional information to me, it seems somehow ingress try to handle request but cannot connect to service?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem was with used port 8000 for websocket server. Used port was not open on firewall, after changing websocket server port to 80, everything started working.